# how to alter all tables at once on postgresql for rebuilding sequences & indexes on a same-named column

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

**first, some context might be useful :**

psql (PostgreSQL) 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1)

I made both a pg_dumpall and pg_dump type backups this morning, so I can modify many things.

I'm not new to sql but I am new to the good way using it and advanced requests.

**My goal**

my goal is to take this existing database with many historical errors & bad habits & even mistakes existing in it & optimize that to something nicer.

**What I have already done**

I dropped triggers procedures & sequences (*until most of them were not working fine or even made mess in existing data*).

I rename the '*ref*' column on all tables to standardize it.

**What I need help for**

I want to execute some plsql code *(I guess)*, to rest all ref columns on all the tables and make it index as prymary-key auto-increment not null & sequence with reset of its counter.

I think something like a loop doing :

```
on all tables 
 drop all ref columns
 create new ref with dedicated sequence starting at zero
 fill the column with the counter
 create the primary key auto-increment-not null on it & on column date when it exists
end of loop
```

I do not really understand how to do so :

```
DO 
$$
DECLARE variable; 
BEGIN
FOR ......where ... LOOP
execute 'alter table.....' || action || action || ' do something'
end loop ;
end ; 
$$;
```

but I don't see what to do nor how to loop that all

Comment: To loop in a resultset you have to work with cursors. This link will be helpful for that. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-cursor/

Comment: for now I failed to apply it properly I had to restore DB after tesing this method